# Dynamically generated Favicon Icon is very small in IE and edge.

Tags: javascript, dom, html, favicon

I am trying to call API which return binary data (base64). When I upload an image,it get stored in the DB in binary format and page icon gets dynamically updated. In chrome and Firefox, page icon is visible and work as expected. However in Edge and IE, image looks too small and stretched. Someone have any idea what should I do?

```
  document.title = title;
            var src = "api/file/getPageLogo";
            src = src + '?=' + Math.random(); 
            var link = document.createElement('link'),
                oldLink = document.getElementById('dynamic-favicon');
            link.id = 'dynamic-favicon';
            link.rel = 'icon';
            link.href = src;
            if (oldLink) {
                document.head.removeChild(oldLink);
            }
            document.head.appendChild(link);
```

[Does not work in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcLU2.jpg)

[Works in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrPdn.jpg)

Comment: what is the file type and dimensions and content of the file

Comment: Original file which is allowed to be uploaded is in png format, dimensions is 32*32. The file is stored in binary format in the DB which looks like 0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D494844520000.......

Comment: Maybe check out this site? https://realfavicongenerator.net He has an FAQ page that explains a lot and an API that might be able to get you a file that works in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual problem was even if the image dimensions were 32*32, while converting it into base64 format, the code was converting dimensions to 200 * 60 which was required to achieve the other functionality.

```
var base64Data = FileTools.GetResizedImageBase64FromDataUri(image.FileData, 200, 60);
```

simply by separating the logic's to achieve two different functionality and changing the dimension of one to 32*32 solved the issue.